# Call a Web Service WSDL with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, web-services

PLEASE can someone help me before I go stir crazy in trying to figure this out. I am a SQL DBA that has self taught myself some VB.NET to interact with the SQL databases we have in-house for data input etc.

I have a web service that I am trying to build a 'Loader' for as the provided Java based one the company in question gave us cannot deal with multiple files and can only deal with one file at a time.

https://openinterchange.openecommerce.co.uk/OpenInterchange/OpenInterchange?wsdl

This is the URL of the WSDL. I have some automation software that has an inbuilt WebService/WCF Executer, while this is great to look at and does the job it doesn't work with my .NET so I am having to do this myself manually.

Essentially I need to fire some XML using a particular FUNCTION from the above WSDL to return a response to my application.

Now according to the automation program it uses the 'OpenInterchange' Class and then uses the OpenInterchange.XStreamMessage(x,x,x,x,1) METHOD to return the information.

I ended up with something along the lines of

```
    Dim MyService As New XstreamUAT.xStreamMessageRequest(brokreftxtbx.Text, bnumtxtbx.Text, lickeytxtbx.Text, "This", 30)

    Dim MyResult As New XstreamUAT.xStreamMessageResponse(MyService.ToString)

    MsgBox(MyResult)
```

But I'm getting nothing, I am obviously completely missing the point. I can't give you details to login to their WSDL but with the link I think there is enough information there to point me in the right direction.

**UPDATE**

I changed some of my code and added:

```
Public Class Form1
Implements XstreamUAT.OpenInterchange
```

and then this updated the bottom of my VB with loads of functions, however they are all empty...

```
Public Function getMessages(request As XstreamUAT.getMessagesRequest) As XstreamUAT.getMessagesResponse Implements XstreamUAT.OpenInterchange.getMessages

End Function

Public Function inStreamMessage(request As XstreamUAT.inStreamMessageRequest) As XstreamUAT.inStreamMessageResponse Implements XstreamUAT.OpenInterchange.inStreamMessage

End Function

Public Function processMessage(request As XstreamUAT.processMessageRequest) As XstreamUAT.processMessageResponse Implements XstreamUAT.OpenInterchange.processMessage

End Function

Public Function returnResponse(request As XstreamUAT.returnResponseRequest) As XstreamUAT.returnResponseResponse Implements XstreamUAT.OpenInterchange.returnResponse

End Function

Public Function xStreamMessage(request As XstreamUAT.xStreamMessageRequest) As XstreamUAT.xStreamMessageResponse Implements XstreamUAT.OpenInterchange.xStreamMessage

End Function
```

Obviously these Functions return nothing, can someone pleas eadd the WSDL and tell me where I'm going wrong here, I'm pulling my hair out and the lack of information on the web for this particular WSDL is doing me over.

I am supposed to be able to fire data to the service using the xStreamMessage Method from the OpenInterchange Class and then return the response back from the web service, I can't even get it to send the Message!! :(

Cheers.

Comment: Google "Add Service Reference".

Comment: Have already done that @JohnSaunders ;)

Its not that part its correctly firing the XML off using the methods in the WSDL I'm having issues with. My code is probably miles off.

Looking at it it looks like its the OpenInterchage Class and then the Method within that Class but I can't seem to reference the class in my code or the method.

Comment: See http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/. Otherwise, I think maybe you're not getting the concept. Your form should almost certainly not be implementing that interface.

Comment: Sussed it out!

Dim client As New XstreamUAT.OpenInterchangeClient()
Dim XMLResponseTxt= client.xStreamMessage(brokreftxtbx.Text, bnumtxtbx.Text, lickeytxtbx.Text, "This", 10)

Comment: You should add that as an answer and say how you figured it out. It may help others. You can even accept your answer if  you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim client As New XstreamUAT.OpenInterchangeClient() 
Dim XMLResponseTxt= client.xStreamMessage(brokreftxtbx.Text, bnumtxtbx.Text, lickeytxtbx.Text, "This", 10)
```

I was declaring the wrong objects for the task in question. In the end I expanded on this with the following code:

```
        'Specify the binding to be used for the client.
        Dim binding As New BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport)

        'Specify the address to be used for the client.
        Dim address As New EndpointAddress(hubURLtxtbx.Text)

        ' Create a client that is configured with this address and binding.
        Dim client As New XstreamLIVE.OpenInterchangeClient(binding, address)

        GlobalVariables.response = client.xStreamMessage(brokreftxtbx.Text, bnumtxtbx.Text, lickeytxtbx.Text, "This", 10)
        XMLResponseTxtBx.Text = PrettyXML(GlobalVariables.response)
```